# Flexbox Layout Fails in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create an overlay that drops down from a header obscuring the page content. This overlay needs to have a footer that is not hidden as the content of the overlay grows. Due to it's dynamic nature I turned to flexbox.

I have a codepen with the behavior that I'm trying to achieve working in Chrome and Firefox. https://codepen.io/Branhammer/pen/KZOJxJ/

Here is the code in a snippet:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

.app {
    height: 100vh;
    background: cadetblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: auto;
}

/**
 * Note that this demo will actually work fine in IE10. This is because in IE10, flex-shrink is 0 instead of 1.  See: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#6-the-default-flex-value-has-changed
 **/
.header {
    height: 50px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background: orchid;
    position: relative;
}

/**
 * 1. IE9-11 do not support main el, so display: block is needed.
 * 2. IE10 sets flex-shrink to zero. This was originally according to spec, but has since changed. See: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#6-the-default-flex-value-has-changed
 **/
.main {
    display: block; /* 1 */
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1; /* 2 */
    background: blanchedalmond;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.footer {
    height: 50px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background: coral;
}

.overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay-content {
    width: 1000px;
    background: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.overlay-content-body {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.overlay-content-footer {
    background: blue;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
}
p {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body class="app">
    <header class="header"></header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <div class="overlay-content-body">
                    <h1>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
                    <p>Fruitcake macaroon candy canes marshmallow gummi bears biscuit I love dessert. Oat cake sugar plum marzipan gummi bears marshmallow I love brownie jelly bonbon. Sweet roll apple pie wafer fruitcake. Gummi bears lemon drops sesame snaps.
                    Biscuit tiramisu sugar plum. Carrot cake pastry cupcake tootsie roll chocolate jujubes. Pudding muffin sweet. Cheesecake candy canes wafer gingerbread sweet.</p>
                    <p>Fruitcake macaroon candy canes marshmallow gummi bears biscuit I love dessert. Oat cake sugar plum marzipan gummi bears marshmallow I love brownie jelly bonbon. Sweet roll apple pie wafer fruitcake. Gummi bears lemon drops sesame snaps.
                    Biscuit tiramisu sugar plum. Carrot cake pastry cupcake tootsie roll chocolate jujubes. Pudding muffin sweet. Cheesecake candy canes wafer gingerbread sweet.</p>
                
            </div>
            <div class="overlay-content-footer">
                footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text footer text
            </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <main class="main">
            <h1>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
            <p>Fruitcake macaroon candy canes marshmallow gummi bears biscuit I love dessert. Oat cake sugar plum marzipan gummi bears marshmallow I love brownie jelly bonbon. Sweet roll apple pie wafer fruitcake. Gummi bears lemon drops sesame snaps.
                    Biscuit tiramisu sugar plum. Carrot cake pastry cupcake tootsie roll chocolate jujubes. Pudding muffin sweet. Cheesecake candy canes wafer gingerbread sweet.</p>
            <p>Fruitcake macaroon candy canes marshmallow gummi bears biscuit I love dessert. Oat cake sugar plum marzipan gummi bears marshmallow I love brownie jelly bonbon. Sweet roll apple pie wafer fruitcake. Gummi bears lemon drops sesame snaps.
                    Biscuit tiramisu sugar plum. Carrot cake pastry cupcake tootsie roll chocolate jujubes. Pudding muffin sweet. Cheesecake candy canes wafer gingerbread sweet.</p>
            <p>Fruitcake macaroon candy canes marshmallow gummi bears biscuit I love dessert. Oat cake sugar plum marzipan gummi bears marshmallow I love brownie jelly bonbon. Sweet roll apple pie wafer fruitcake. Gummi bears lemon drops sesame snaps. Biscuit
                tiramisu sugar plum. Carrot cake pastry cupcake tootsie roll chocolate jujubes. Pudding muffin sweet. Cheesecake candy canes wafer gingerbread sweet.</p>
            <p>Liquorice candy canes cake. Gummies wafer tart topping pastry soufflé I love pie. Cake cookie croissant cupcake chocolate cake. Liquorice jelly beans pudding sugar plum biscuit fruitcake. Soufflé tootsie roll macaroon pudding. Chocolate cake
                cake sesame snaps sugar plum biscuit I love croissant icing. Caramels jelly dessert candy bonbon bear claw chocolate bar cheesecake icing. Toffee I love cake gingerbread jelly-o tootsie roll. Sesame snaps pie cupcake sweet. Croissant danish
                brownie gummies lollipop chupa chups gummies danish.</p>
            <p>Chupa chups pudding topping caramels pie. Tart jujubes ice cream muffin sugar plum. Soufflé candy canes I love lollipop pastry brownie danish apple pie. Apple pie chupa chups biscuit chocolate bar I love muffin I love. Caramels cupcake I love
                sugar plum icing candy canes I love macaroon. Marzipan danish cheesecake marshmallow jelly. Jelly-o sugar plum liquorice donut I love pastry candy donut. I love gummi bears chocolate.</p>
            <p>Gingerbread toffee pastry gingerbread I love toffee. Biscuit jelly wafer I love cheesecake candy canes chocolate cake. I love cake I love cotton candy muffin oat cake I love I love. I love bonbon macaroon toffee powder chupa chups cotton candy
                tootsie roll chocolate. Croissant dessert chocolate bar. Apple pie I love croissant sugar plum cotton candy I love. Candy canes jelly I love. Jelly beans cupcake brownie pudding lemon drops</p>
            <p>Cheesecake macaroon toffee sesame snaps cotton candy cotton candy I love. Cake sugar plum sweet marshmallow I love. Soufflé liquorice ice cream candy canes I love tootsie roll marzipan biscuit jelly. I love I love tiramisu donut. I love bear
                claw pastry toffee. Cheesecake apple pie bonbon bear claw jelly-o topping tootsie roll chocolate bar. Cake bonbon toffee donut macaroon chocolate lemon drops gummies gummies. Jelly beans chocolate bar cotton candy halvah fruitcake.</p>
        </main>
        <footer class="footer"></footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

I need this to work in IE as well. I'm seeing that the footer flex behavior is not working. Anything thoughts on how to remedy this?

Comment: To see what I'm trying to accomplish in the snippet or in the codepen you need to play with the window size of the result. It should be obvious then. In chrome the yellow body of the overlay will scroll while the footer will stay it's size and visible on the screen.

Comment: I don't manage to reproduce your bug. I tried with micrsoft Edge and use the emulator to set up to IE11. I saw just the behaviour was slower than in Firefox.

Comment: IE11 requires a defined height on the `.overlay-content-body` element. `overflow-y: auto` is not working on its own, like in other browsers. I'm sorry I don't have the time right now to delve deeper. But that seems to be the source of the problem in IE11.